# Obj-C how to add lock for C++ singletion in multi-thread env?

Tags: ios, multithreading, locking

In my app the network request secret key exchange is written by C++ and linked by library in my xcode project. It is not thread safe, which means if two threads encrypt or decrypt at the same time then unexpected behavior will happen. I always invoke it in this way.

```
TnKeyChangeInstance::instance()->encrypt(inStr, outStr);
```

You know, `@synchronized` only works for `NSObject` type object, how do I add a lock for C++ code, as the above singleton? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`NSRecursiveLock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRecursiveLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
@interface MyClassUsingTnKeyChangeInstance : ... { 
  NSRecursiveLock *lock;
}
@end

@implementation MySafeMutableArray


<instantiate the lock in your init method>

- (void)lockedOp:(id)obj {
   [self.lock lock];
   <access singleton>
   [self.lock unlock];
}

@end
```

This approach requires that you access the singleton exclusively through `MyClassUsingTnKeyChangeInstance` (which is a constraint similar to the one posed by `@synchronized`). If you need to access the singleton in a thread safe way, you need to put the lock elsewhere and ensure that you lock/unlock it each time that you access it.

Another approach, removing altogether the possibility of deadlocking, is using a GCD serial queue to serialise all accesses to the singleton. In this case, you would create a wrapper for your singleton class and then call each of its methods like this:

```
- (void)serializeOp:(id)obj {
    dispatch_sync(self.serialQueue, ^{ <access singleton> });
}
```

A final approach would be modifying your singleton C++ implementation and add a `std::mutex::lock` to it in order to make it thread-safe. In this case you would modify all the singleton methods to add `mutex.lock()/mutex.unlock()` calls to them. This approach could be the best if the singleton implementation is not overly complex, and better yet if you make your thread-safe changes in a class derived from the implementation you have.